# Hamburger menu toggle state issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Currently I'm working on a Next.js blog project and I would like to implement hamburger menu, but when I click on the hamburger button nothing happens. This is my first project. I provide the source code.

This is the `Layout` component:

```js
import Backdrop from "../BackDrop/Backdrop";
import Navigation from "../Navigation/Navigation";
import SideDrawer from "../SideDrawer/SideDrawer";
import { useState } from "react";

function Layout(props) {
  const [sideDrawerOpen, setSideDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  function toogleClickHandler() {
    setSideDrawerOpen((prevState) => {
      return { sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen };
    });
  }

  let sideDrawer;
  let backdrop;

  if (sideDrawerOpen) {
    sideDrawer: <SideDrawer />;
    backdrop: <Backdrop />;
  }
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Navigation drawerClickHandler={toogleClickHandler} />
      {sideDrawer}
      {backdrop}
      <main style={{ marginTop: "64px" }}>{props.children}</main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

This `Layout` component wraps all components in `_app.js` file:

```js
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../Components/Layout/Layout";
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

These are the three components what the `Layout` component is using:

`Navigation.js` component:

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import Logo from "../Logo/Logo";
import classes from "./Navigation.module.css";
import DrawerToggleButton from "../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton";

function Navigation(props) {
  return (
    <header className={classes.header}>
      <nav className={classes.nav}>
        <div>
          <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>
              <Logo />
            </a>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.spacer}></div>
        <div className={classes.navItems}>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link href="/">
                <a>Home</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/allposts">
                <a>All Posts</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/featuredposts">
                <a>Featured Posts</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/Products">
                <a>Products</a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
export default Navigation;
```

This is the `SideDrawer` component:

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import classes from "./SideDrawer.module.css";

const SideDrawer = (props) => {
  return (
    <nav className={classes.sideDrawer}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Home</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/allposts">
            <a>All Posts</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/featuredposts">
            <a>Featured Posts</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/products">
            <a>Products</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

This is the `Backdrop` component:

```js
import classes from "./Backdrop.module.css";

function Backdrop(props) {
  return <div className={classes.backdrop}></div>;
}

export default Backdrop;
```

The `Navigation` component using this `DrawerToggleButton`. This is the `DrawerToggleButton` component:

```js
import classes from "./DrawerToggleButton.module.css";

const DrawerToggleButton = (props) => (
  <button className={classes.button} onClick={props.click}>
    <div className={classes.line} />
    <div className={classes.line} />
    <div className={classes.line} />
  </button>
);

export default DrawerToggleButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three issues to sort out here. First off, your Navigation component is looking for `props.click` but your Layout component is sending a prop called  `drawerClickHandler`. In addition, you should pass a mouse event handler or handle the mouse event and call the click function. Finally, when you want to toggle state in `setSideDrawerOpen`, you should get the previous state and use that to set/toggle the value:

```js
// Layout Component
import Backdrop from "../BackDrop/Backdrop";
import Navigation from "../Navigation/Navigation";
import SideDrawer from "../SideDrawer/SideDrawer";
import { useState } from "react";

function Layout(props) {
  const [sideDrawerOpen, setSideDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  function toogleClickHandler() {
    // Use the previous state to set the new state
    setSideDrawerOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  }

  let sideDrawer;
  let backdrop;

  if (sideDrawerOpen) {
    sideDrawer: <SideDrawer />;
    backdrop: <Backdrop />;
  }
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      // Let's pass this prop to the Navigation - see the change I make in that component
      <Navigation drawerClickHandler={toogleClickHandler} />
      {sideDrawer}
      {backdrop}
      <main style={{ marginTop: "64px" }}>{props.children}</main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;

// Navigation Component
import classes from "./DrawerToggleButton.module.css";

// Two changes here. First, use the correct prop name. Second, `onClick`
// should be a function that calls your prop/function
const DrawerToggleButton = (props) => (
  <button className={classes.button} onClick={() => props.drawerClickHandler}>
    <div className={classes.line} />
    <div className={classes.line} />
    <div className={classes.line} />
  </button>
);

export default DrawerToggleButton;
```

Comment: Hello! First of all thank you for answer to me, i appreciate it. I tried your advices but the toggle menu button still not working. By the way i just passed the toggleClickHandler function as a reference through props to DrawerToggleButton component. Furthermore i found an interesting thing in Layout component:  Vs code signs the  sideDrawer and
  backdrop variables with gray color in the if statement and when i hover over it vs code said unused label. I will fix this issue .

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be with your setSideDrawerOpen.

Instead of this:

```
function toogleClickHandler() {
    setSideDrawerOpen((prevState) => {
      return { sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen };
    });
  }
```

Try this instead?

```
function toogleClickHandler() {
    setSideDrawerOpen(!sideDrawerOpen);
  }
```

Comment: Hello ! I tried your solution but the button still doesn't work. :( :( :(